# AWS DynamoDB conditional get

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I just started using DynamoDB, I can't figure out the most effiecient way of retrieving user data only when the `SSID` is valid.

Current Method:

```js
import {DynamoDB} from "aws-sdk"
import * as cookie from "cookie"
import {forObject} from "../../scripts/Common";
import StatusError from "../../classes/StatusError";

export default async function ({headers}) {
    const {UNAME, SSID} = cookie.parse(headers.Cookie)
    const res = (await new DynamoDB.DocumentClient().get({
        TableName: 'WB360-USERS',
        Key: {
            UNAME
        },
        AttributesToGet: ["ARTICLES", "SSID"]
    }).promise()).Item;
    if(res.SSID !== SSID)
        throw new StatusError("Invalid SSID",401);
    delete res.SSID;
    return forObject({},res)
}
```

In the above method I am retrieving the full list of `ARTICLES` and `SSID` for the given user, and then comparing the fetched `SSID` with the one in the cookies. This method is very inefficient.

**Is there a better way of retieving data only if a condition is valid**

**ENV** NodeJS with TS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading `@Rafael Almeida`'s answer, I figured out that [querying](https://www.dynamodbguide.com/querying/) is the best approach for this problem.

```js
const res = (await new DynamoDB.DocumentClient().query({
        TableName: 'WB360-USERS',
        KeyConditionExpression: 'UNAME = :U ',
        FilterExpression: 'SSID = :S',
        ProjectionExpression: "ARTICLES",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':S': SSID,
            ':U': UNAME
        }
    }).promise()).Items[0];

if (!res)
   return forError(new StatusError("Invalid SSID or UNAME", 401));
return forObject({}, res)
```

Here if `res` is undefined then `SSID` was not valid and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Filter Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression) in your query. Note that your query will just return what matches, but you will still be billed by each item evaluated.

Also, consider your keys. Depending on your access patterns, you can have the user ID as partition key and SSID as sort key. This way you can get a document from the user ID + SSID in constant time (that it, always performing a single operation, irrespective of table size). Be sure to read the [Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html) doc to get a feel for the best ways of modeling and accessing your data.